# Need help to configure CanCanCan for activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancancan

I need help to configure CanCanCan using ActiveAdmin. I have everything else working including devise. I can restrict menus using devise but if you know the URL lets say for edit you can still edit that resource. I want to restrict a normal user from editing/creating any resources but it does not seem to work.

Active_Admin.rb

```
config.cancan_ability_class = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
```

Ability.rb (simple out of the box)

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
      # user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, Student
      else
        can :read, Student
      end
end
end
```

User model.

```
admin:boolean
```

and if I login with a user who is not an admin i can still create/edit/delete, I just want to restrict them to read only.

Please help i am struggling with this only feature that I need to complete.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this thinks:

```
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
config.cancan_ability_class = Ability
```

`authorization_adapter` tells active admin which adapter it should be use.
`cancan_ability_class` tells the adapter which class it should use.

If that still doesn't work, try to rename `Ability` to `AdminAbility`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I added the ability class, but now it goes into a forever loop and says localhost not started even though it is.

I also renamed the class to AdminAbility but it gives me uninitialized constant AdminAbility (NameError) on server start up

Comment: hey just to let you know after I played around with it more, i got it working, your answer is correct, I was just getting  white page and when I checked the logs it said no permission for this page, i thought it was a loop but it wasnt. Thanks